# Using DataBound to display duplicates and disable button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a databound function that would disable the save and print button, however when I refresh the page the button enables or remove the duplicate row is remove then it is still disabled,  I would like to know how to stop this.

Update

```
protected void AssignInvoice_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int ThisRow = 0; ThisRow < AssignInvoice.Rows.Count - 1; ThisRow++)
            {
                GridViewRow CompareRow = AssignInvoice.Rows[ThisRow];
                for (int NextRow = ThisRow + 1; NextRow < AssignInvoice.Rows.Count; NextRow++)
                {
                    GridViewRow row = AssignInvoice.Rows[NextRow];
                    bool DuplicateRow = true;
                    if ((CompareRow.Cells[3].Text) == (row.Cells[3].Text))
                    {
                        
                        CompareRow.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#F5ECAB");
                        row.Cells[3].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        CompareRow.BackColor = Color.FromName("#F5ECAB");
                        CompareRow.Cells[3].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        CompareRow.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;
                        row.Cells[3].Font.Bold = true;
                        Print.Enabled = false;
                        Save.Enabled = false;
                    }
                    else if (DuplicateRow)
                    {
                        DuplicateRow = false;
                        Print.Enabled = true;
                        Save.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Post your PageLoad function code here.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                    
                   
                    showData();

                    

                }

Comment: Seems the problem is in the `foreach (GridViewRow row in AssignInvoice.Rows)` loop. What you trying to achieve here?

Comment: loop through to find duplicates

Comment: The issue is with the buttons

Comment: @SelvaS, I've updated what I have but the buttons not working

Comment: Set buttons default, disabled = true and enable it wherever required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228488/discussion-between-sue-and-selvas).

Comment: @SelvaS, I set the button enabled=false but that doesn't work

Comment: Print.Enabled = true;
                        Save.Enabled = true; this in the right place

Comment: @SelvaS, I want to enable it when there's ni duplicates